# Elasticsearch with Kubernetes: Memory lock with bootstrap.memory_lock does not work

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, memory-locking

I'm currently struggling with the k8s setup for our used elasticsearch with version 2.4.6:

Disable the memory swapping with bootstrap.memory_lock does not work. Memory reservation is failing with the well known error:

```
[2020-05-22 21:12:22,762][WARN ][bootstrap                ] Unable to lock JVM Memory: error=12,reason=Cannot allocate memory
[2020-05-22 21:12:22,764][WARN ][bootstrap                ] This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out.
[2020-05-22 21:12:22,765][WARN ][bootstrap                ] Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, soft limit: 83968000, hard limit: 83968000
[2020-05-22 21:12:22,765][WARN ][bootstrap                ] These can be adjusted by modifying /etc/security/limits.conf, for example:
        # allow user 'elasticsearch' mlockall
        elasticsearch soft memlock unlimited
        elasticsearch hard memlock unlimited
```

I basically tried to follow the guidelines from this source: [Memory Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/setup-configuration.html#setup-configuration-memory) but it's still not properly running.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
  name: elasticsearch
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: elasticsearch:2.4.6
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: elasticsearch
        env:
         - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
           value: "-Xmx512m -Xms512m"
         - name: ES_HEAP_SIZE
           value: "1g"
         - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
           value: "true"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
        - containerPort: 9300
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
          subPath: elasticsearch.yml
          name: elasticsearch-config
      initContainers:
          -   name: fix-permissions
              image: alpine:3.6
              command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
              securityContext:
                  privileged: true
              volumeMounts:
                  -   name: elasticsearch-data
                      mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          -   name: increase-vm-max-map
              image: alpine:3.6
              command: ["/sbin/sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
              securityContext:
                  privileged: true
          -   name: fix-ulimit
              image: alpine:3.6
              command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
              securityContext:
                  privileged: true
      hostname: elasticsearch
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes:
      - name: elasticsearch-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: elasticsearch-data
      - name: elasticsearch-config
        configMap:
          name: elasticsearch-config
```

Can post configmap and pvc if needed but i think they are not really related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't fix it, it's very possible that Elasticsearch running in a container does not have the required system permissions.

`mlockall` is only required if you have swap enabled, which is uncommon on modern systems. If you don't have any swap space configured, don't worry about `mlockall`.